# Can cairo load a PDF?

Tags: cairo, pycairo

This sounds really simple, but I can't find a way to load a PDF into Cairo. I want to be able to do `cairo.PDFSurface.create_from_pdf` in the same way I do `cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png` (yes I'm using the Python bindings but that's neither here nor there).

The [documentation](http://www.cairographics.org/manual/cairo-PDF-Surfaces.html) doesn't appear to give any hints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, cairo cannot read PDFs. However, poppler can load PDFs an paint them onto a cairo context - http://poppler.freedesktop.org/

(Oh and create_from_png() is part of cairo's toy API. It works, but you are recommended to use some "real" API which can do more things than just loading PNGs)

Example code to render a PDF get it into a pycairo `ImageSurface`:

```py
import io
from pathlib import Path

import cairo
import poppler
from PIL import Image

filepath = Path('test.pdf')
document = poppler.load_from_file(filepath)

renderer = poppler.PageRenderer()

# Render first page and convert to image buffer
page = document.create_page(0)
image = renderer.render_page(page, xres=72, yres=72)
buf = io.BytesIO(image.data).getbuffer()

if False: # for debugging
    pil_img = Image.frombytes('RGBA', (image.width, image.height),
                              image.data, 'raw', str(image.format))
    pil_img.save('test.png')

# Use page dimensions to create cairo surface
rect = page.page_rect()
width = int(rect.width)
height = int(rect.height)
#print(f'bytes used per pixel: {len(buf)/(width*height)}')

surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_for_data(buf, cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, width, height)
```

The resulting `surface` can be used as input to `Context.set_source_surface()` to paint onto an existing PDFSurface. If the resulting PDF shows a grainy image, increasing `xres` or `yres` by a factor of 72 can help, but this creates a need to scale down before painting.

Comment: Thanks very much. I didn't realise another library was needed on top of Cairo. FWIW `create_from_png` may be part of the toy interface but it does the job for me!